# R: Create suplots for each row in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, bar-chart, subplot

I have the following dataframe:

```
V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
A  0  3  1  0
R  4  2  0  0
Q  0  2  4  0
```

V1 is the identifier and the residual columns resemble the actual data.

I want to create barplots for every row in this dataframe. I tried using `melt` to reshape into long format and vectorize the problem but was not succesful. Is there a way that does not require writing a function?

EDIT:
This is what I would like to see in the end (just the principle layout):

https://plot.ly/~MattSundquist/11035.png

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grouped bar Graph using barplot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14544124/grouped-bar-graph-using-barplot)

Comment: I do not want to group them as asked for in the other question. I want to have seperate plots using `par`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about doing it this way?

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df_n <- gather(df, key = V1)
names(df_n) <- letters[1:3]
ggplot(df_n, aes(a, c, fill=b)) + geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity")
```

[image]

EDITED version:

Using faceting:

```
ggplot(df_n, aes(a, c, fill=b)) + geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity") + facet_grid(.~a, scales = "free")
```

[image]

Comment: Really nice. But again I require subplots not a single one. Thanks.

Comment: What about faceting?

Comment: I have little experience with R. Sorry for that. I wanted to have some nice subplots and have seen some good use of `par(mfrow=c(n,m))`. Therefore I imported my data with the `read.csv`function. Appearently, plotting from the data.frame is not that straightforward. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want:

```
d<-data.frame(V1=c('A','R','Q'),V2=c(0,4,0),
               V3=c(3,2,2),V4=c(1,0,4),V5=c(0,0,0))
rownames(d)<-d[,1]
barplot(t(as.matrix(d[,-1])),beside=T) # barplots for group A, R, Q.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It does plot everything but in one plot. I would like to use `par(mfrow=c(2,2))` later on.

Comment: Then try: `par(mfrow=c(2,2)); apply(d[,-1],2,barplot)`

Comment: That generates several plots, as intended, but has all the values in each plot.

Answer (score 0):

I did one column only, but you get the idea I think:

```
df = data.frame(v1 = c('A', 'R', 'Q'), v2 = c(0,4,0))
dat1 = split(df, df$v1)
str(dat1)
lapply(dat1, FUN=function(x) ggplot(data=x, aes(v1, v2)) + geom_bar(stat="identity"))
```