# How to edit the numbers on ggplot y axis

Tags: r, bar-chart

I am trying to create a nice barplot for my data. So far I have been using the ggplot function:

```
    library(ggplot2)
    ggplot(dframe1, aes(x=Site, y=lambda.max)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
    labs(x="Site", y="Lambda maximum")
```

[image: This is so far what I have come up with]

The data on the y axis needs to be in the hundreds though (not the thousands), and I do not know how to change that. Also I was wondering if it is possible to represent all of this data on one barplot or graph?:

```
    structure(list(Site = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("6", 
    "2", "3", "4", "5"), class = "factor"), weight = c(0.193, 0.249, 
    0.263, 0.262, 0.419, 0.204, 0.311, 0.481, 0.326, 0.657, 0.347, 
    0.239, 0.416, 0.31, 0.314, 0.277, 0.302, 0.403), cell.count = c(2530000, 
    729000, 336000, 436000, 292000, 0, 2e+05, 6450000, 2e+05, 18700000, 
    7430000, 9920000, 22700000, 21600000, 227000, 169000, 5e+05, 
    283000), eleocyte = c(1270000, 17, 7.3, 264000, 0, 0, 2e+05, 
    0, 2e+05, 2270000, 0, 9920000, 22700000, 442, 153000, 169000, 
    5e+05, 283000), lambda.max = c(459L, 459L, 459L, 459L, 462L, 
    462L, 462L, 462L, 462L, 465L, 465L, 465L, 465L, 490L, 490L, 475L, 
    475L, 475L), avepb.ppm = c(390.2, 373.3, 340.13, 403.2, 248.53, 
    206.7, 238.5, 190.6, 597.2, 206.8, 174.4, 186.3, 138.5, 269.55, 
    58.1, 5.225, 4.02, 6.85), aveworm.pb.ppm = c(9.59, 9.446, 4.193, 
    21.9, 1.66, 7.415, 13.11, 3.01, 51.5, 5.985, 4.705, 26.38, 2.38, 
    4.44, 4.67, 0.11, 0.085, 0.096), aveworm.g = c(0.09125, 0.264, 
    14.699, 0.2425, 0.4793, 0.051, 0.0635, 0.0465, 0.2645, 0.0559, 
    0.0795, 0.05765, 0.0846, 0.457, 0.0625, 0.0535, 0.1576, 0.16)), .Names = c("Site", 
    "weight", "cell.count", "eleocyte", "lambda.max", "avepb.ppm", 
    "aveworm.pb.ppm", "aveworm.g"), row.names = c(NA, -18L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: What to you want to happen when there are multiple entries per site? (At the moment you are seeing the sum of values which is why they are "in the thousands".)

Comment: I see. Is it possible to show the replicates for each site, each with its associated value?

Answer (score 1):

***(1) How to change the y to be hundred separated***

The [continuous_y_axis](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/scale_continuous.html) gives you a few options like `comma`, `dollar`, `percent`. I don't think the hundred you want is built in.

However, you can simply divide the y by the unit (100) in this case. And add the unit to your y label.

```
library(ggplot2)
unit <- 100
ggplot(dframe1, aes(x=Site, y=lambda.max/unit)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
  labs(x="Site", y=paste0("Lambda maximum: Unit: ", unit))
```

[image]

***(2) Can I fit all the data into one plot***

I don't think it is a good idea to fit all the variables into one plot. Like the dodged bar plot [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148956/how-to-create-grouped-barplot-with-r). Because all the variables are in different scale and if you fit all of them into one plot. Some of them will be unnoticable.

Here is what [facet_wrap](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/facet_wrap.html) and [reshape](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v21/i12/paper) can do for you.

```
library(reshape2)
dframe2 <- melt(dframe1, id="Site")
ggplot(dframe2, aes(x=Site, y=value)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") + facet_wrap(~variable, scales="free")
```

[image]

***(3) DONT SUM WITHIN GROUP***

In that case, all the records inside each site need to be treated as an individual record, in that case, I created a variable called row for each record, you can improve that part.

```
dframe1$row <- row.names(dframe1)
library(reshape2)
dframe2 <- melt(dframe1, id=c("Site", "row"))
ggplot(dframe2, aes(x=as.numeric(row), fill=Site, y=value)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") + facet_wrap(~variable, scales="free")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. However, as @BondedDust pointed out to me, is there a way to show the replicates for each site instead of just the summation for each site?

Comment: Sorry I am also having problems running the R script you have suggested. I get this error: Error in packageVersion("plyr") : package ‘plyr’ not found. I have installed this package, as well as reshape 2..

Comment: I have finally managed to reproduce the graph..however, how do you add the different colours? Is a new package needed? Link to picture of graph:http://i.imgur.com/Fc1eLcG.jpg