# Create a grouped barplot in R using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a grouped barplot using ggplot due to the more aesthetically pleasing quality it produces. I have a dataframe, together, containing the values and the name of each value but I can't manage to create the plot it? the dataframe is as follows

```
          USperReasons      USperReasonsNY                 USuniquNegR
1    0.198343304187759   0.191304347826087                 Late Flight
2     0.35987114588127   0.321739130434783      Customer Service Issue
3   0.0667280257708237    0.11304347826087                Lost Luggage
4   0.0547630004601933 0.00869565217391304     Flight Booking Problems
5    0.109065807639208   0.121739130434783                  Can't Tell
6  0.00460193281178095                   0             Damaged Luggage
7   0.0846755637367694  0.0782608695652174            Cancelled Flight
8   0.0455591348366314  0.0521739130434783                  Bad Flight
9   0.0225494707777266  0.0347826086956522                   longlines
10  0.0538426138978371  0.0782608695652174 Flight Attendant Complaints
```

I tried different methods with errors in all, one such example is below

```
ggplot(together,aes(USuniquNegR, USperReasons,USperReasonsNY))+ geom_bar(position = "dodge")
```

Thanks,
Alan.

Comment: It is unclear what your expected result is, and there is no signs of you attempting to solve this yourself.

Comment: there are several examples of grouped barplots with ggplot2 on SO

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create grouped barplot with R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148956/how-to-create-grouped-barplot-with-r)

Comment: Are you sure your data are numeric? What errors are you getting?

Comment: you need to convert your dataset from wide to long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df <- reshape2::melt(together, 3)

ggplot(reshape2::melt(df, 3), 
    aes(USuniquNegR, value, fill = variable)) + 
        geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'dodge') + 
        coord_flip() + 
        theme(legend.position = 'top')
```

[image: Output Plot]