# Grouped Bar Plot Species and plots

Tags: r, plot

Id like to make a grouped barplot that has two groups. One named Exotic Species and the second Native Species. then compare them to the Plot that they are found.Therefore 3 columns are involved with the graph. Y would be "Species Richness" and it would be the number of species either of native or exotic. X will be the "Plot name". How do i write out the coding for the bar graph i described above? If you google search European Parliament Elections R grouped barplot (orange and purply plot. thats what i want

Comment: Can you give a direct link to this Google search you mention?

Comment: This one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007120/grouped-bar-graph

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you want something like this:
[image]

Here is two solutions:

1.**using barplot:** let's say mtcars is the dataframe

```
# Grouped Bar Plot
counts <- table(mtcars$vs, mtcars$gear)
barplot(counts, main="Car Distribution by Gears and VS",
  xlab="Number of Gears", col=c("darkblue","red"),
    legend = rownames(counts), beside=TRUE)
```

[Link](http://www.statmethods.net/graphs/bar.html)

2. **using lattice**

   library(lattice)
   barchart(Species~Reason,data=Reasonstats,groups=Catergory, 
            scales=list(x=list(rot=90,cex=0.8)))

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17721126/simplest-way-to-do-grouped-barplot)