# How to Barplot Grouped Contingency Tables

Tags: r, grouping, bar-chart

I'm using one of the R built-in datasets called `UCBAdmissions` and trying to create a grouped barplot with the data coerced to a dataframe and grouped by `Admit`, `Gender` and `Dept` (without using `ggplot`).

```
data(UCBAdmissions)
as.data.frame(UCBAdmissions)
      Admit Gender Dept Freq
1  Admitted   Male    A  512
2  Rejected   Male    A  313
3  Admitted Female    A   89
4  Rejected Female    A   19
5  Admitted   Male    B  353
6  Rejected   Male    B  207
7  Admitted Female    B   17
8  Rejected Female    B    8
9  Admitted   Male    C  120
10 Rejected   Male    C  205
11 Admitted Female    C  202
12 Rejected Female    C  391
13 Admitted   Male    D  138
14 Rejected   Male    D  279
15 Admitted Female    D  131
16 Rejected Female    D  244
17 Admitted   Male    E   53
18 Rejected   Male    E  138
19 Admitted Female    E   94
20 Rejected Female    E  299
21 Admitted   Male    F   22
22 Rejected   Male    F  351
23 Admitted Female    F   24
24 Rejected Female    F  317
```

I tried converting the data to the table format this way but got an error message.

```
> barplot(table(as.data.frame(UCBAdmissions)))
Error in barplot.default(table(as.data.frame(UCBAdmissions))) : 
  'height' must be a vector or a matrix
```

I found this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148956/how-to-create-grouped-barplot-with-r) link that provided a non-ggplot answer but was getting the error message shown above.

There is also this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007120/grouped-bar-graph) link but the data is structured differently.

I'm hoping the data can be displayed with just two dimensions. Here is what a simplified grouped barplot looks like.

[image: grouped barplot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to achieve, but I'll assume you want bars grouped by Dept, and the legend to be a combination of Gender & Admit (just to give the idea).

In the barplot examples you point to, the data is a pure numeric matrix with rownames and colnames set to the labels and groupings.  You'll need to start by transforming your data (I use `dplyr` and `tidyr` from the `tidyverse`):

```
library(tidyverse)
df2 = group_by(as.data.frame(UCBAdmissions), Dept, Gender, Admit) %>% 
    summarise(Freq = sum(Freq)) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    mutate(GA = paste(Gender, Admit)) %>%
    select(Dept, GA, Freq) %>%
    spread(key = Dept, value = Freq) %>%
    as.data.frame()
rownames(df2) = df2$GA
df2 = as.matrix(select(df2, -GA))
```

Now your data is in a form which barplot can use:

```
barplot(df2, beside=TRUE, legend = rownames(df2))
```

[image: final bar plot]